# Smiley Face using parametric equations

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, homework

I need to know the parametric equations for this smiley face and how to draw it in Mathematica.  I'm completely lost.

[image]

Comment: I need to know how to plot this exact smiley face with the radius of 2.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to this question, but still interesting:  `Entity["Lamina", "SmileyFaceLamina"]["Diagram"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{
  2 {1 + Cos[t], 1 + Sin[t]},
  {2 - Cos[t/2], 2 - Sin[t/2]},
  {1 + Cos[t]/10, 3 + Sin[t]/10},
  {3 + Cos[t]/10, 3 + Sin[t]/10}},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Couple of non-answers, but I hope interesting.

### Chernoff face

So here is another non-answer with a [Chernoff face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_face) diagram [using the package ChernoffFaces.m](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/making-chernoff-faces-for-data-visualization/).

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/ChernoffFaces.m"]

ChernoffFace[<|"MouthSmile" -> 0.8|>]
```

[image]

### Lamina entity

I really liked the comment by @JasonB. of using [lamina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_lamina) entities.

```
Entity["Lamina", "SmileyFaceLamina"]["Diagram"]
```

[image]